# Bootstrap 4 - JavaScript cus

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-sass

I'm trying to change the default text of the of custom-file-input to show it in Spanish.

```
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h2>12. Carga de ficheros customizado</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card-block">
                <form>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="custom-file">
                        <input type="file" id="fileCustom" class="custom-file-input">
                        <span class="custom-file-control"></span>
                    </label>
                    <small id="fileCustom" class="form-text text-muted">Para hacerlo personal
                    hay que envolver en una etiqueta el elemento input.
                    </small>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The JavaScript that I'm using is the suggested in [Translating or customizing the strings](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/?#translating-or-customizing-the-strings) (bottom of the page)

```
$fileCustom: (
  placeholder: (
    en: "Choose file...",
    es: "Seleccionar archivo..."
  ),
  button-label: (
    en: "Browse",
    es: "Navegar"
  )
);
```

I've already changed the language of my document `<html lang="es">` and probably the mistake is in the relation between the javascript and the HTML code but I couldn't find a solution within the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use image that you wanted to view "Seleccionar archivo..." and es: "Navegar"
**You can use below line of codes:**

```
    var W3CDOM = (document.createElement && document.getElementsByTagName);

function initFileUploads() {
    if (!W3CDOM) return;
    var fakeFileUpload = document.createElement('div');
    fakeFileUpload.className = 'fakefile';
    fakeFileUpload.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src='pix/button_select.gif';
    fakeFileUpload.appendChild(image);
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
        if (x[i].type != 'file') continue;
        if (x[i].parentNode.className != 'fileinputs') continue;
        x[i].className = 'file hidden';
        var clone = fakeFileUpload.cloneNode(true);
        x[i].parentNode.appendChild(clone);
        x[i].relatedElement = clone.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        x[i].onchange = x[i].onmouseout = function () {
            this.relatedElement.value = this.value;
        }
    }
}
```

***N:B: You should change the image url from above codes.***